# In BLE is there any limitation of Number of BLE devices interacting on Advertise / scan topology or what are the possible limitations?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

Recently i have started working on BLE for a upcoming project. i will describe the overall system first.

We have a approx 100 BLE device placed in small compartment (all are within the radio range of each other), and have one central device / gateway which will also has BLE and wifi (within the range of all 100 BLE device). we want to update some small amount of data from all 100 BLE devices to cloud through central device / gateway and vice versa. So the question is :-

1. which BLE network topology would be best suitable for such application?
2. If i am going for ADVERTISE / SCAN topology, is it possible to collect the data of all the 100 BLE
   device ?
3. For such number of device is over the air firmware update possible through single gateway ?
4. IS it possible that gateway can request each BLE device one by on and collect data ?

Basically is it possible to collect data of applox. 100 BLE devicesin connection less mode ?

As we are new to BLE development, correct me if my understating is wrong.

Thanks In Advance !!